# Distinct row count Postgresql version prior to 8.3

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that returns to me something like the following:

```
name   | value
John   | 3
John   | 4
John   | 5
Robert | 10
Robert | 6
Robert | 4
```

etc...

I need to show the row_num on distinct names, like this:

```
row_num | name   | value
1       | John   | 3
1       | John   | 4
1       | John   | 5
2       | Robert | 10
2       | Robert | 6
2       | Robert | 4
```

The main problem is that my Postgres version is 8.2, and I can't upgrade it now, so after doing my research I figured out that some useful functions that would help me are not available on my version (like `row_number()`, `generate_series`, etc).

Is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(r.row_num, m.row_max) AS row_num,
  t.name,
  t.value
FROM tmp t
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    r1.name,
    COUNT(*) AS row_num
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tmp) r1
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tmp) r2 
    ON r1.name > r2.name
  GROUP BY 1) r 
    ON t.name = r.name
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS row_max
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM tmp) r3
) m ON True;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on your sample data:

```
select (select count(distinct name) from person p2 where p2.name <= p1.name) as cnt,
       p1.name,
       p1.value
from person p1
order by p1.name;
```

I could only test this on 9.4, but I think it should work on 8.x as well, but it won't be fast.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3580a/1

---

<sup>But you should **really** upgrade to a supported and maintained version</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Old trick to simulate subqueries and CTE's using (temporary) views:

```
CREATE TABLE a (name text, val integer);
INSERT INTO a (name , val ) VALUES
 ('John' , 3 )
, ('John' , 4 )
, ('John' , 5 )
, ('Robert' , 10 )
, ('Robert' , 6 )
, ('Robert' , 4 )
    ;
CREATE VIEW d AS SELECT DISTINCT name FROM a;

CREATE VIEW c AS
SELECT d0.name, COUNT(*) AS rnk
FROM d d0
JOIN d d1 ON d1. name <= d0.name
GROUP BY d0.name
    ;

-- SELECT * FROM d;
-- SELECT * FROM c;

SELECT c.rnk, a.name, a.val
FROM a
JOIN c ON a.name = c.name
    ;

DROP VIEW d;
DROP VIEW c;
```